# How to connect to SQL Server service from Docker in Docker?

Tags: sql-server, docker, asp.net-core, gitlab, gitlab-pipelines

I'm trying to build and run an ASP.NET Core app and test it with newman.
Here's the pipeline I have:

```yaml
services:
  - mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU14-ubuntu-20.04
  - docker:19.03.12-dind

variables:
  VERSION: "0.0.0"
  ACCEPT_EULA: Y
  MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD: *******
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
        
stages:
  - test
 
postman_tests:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - docker
  script:
    - docker run -p 5555:80 -v $(pwd)/CatalogService/:/app/ -w /app -e ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80 -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development -t mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.100-alpine3.14-amd64 dotnet run --project ./CatalogService.csproj
    - sleep 120s
    - docker run -v $(pwd)/test:/etc/newman -t postman/newman:alpine run "CatalogService.postman_collection.json" --reporters="cli"
```

I just started today to learn about Docker and how to use it with the Gitlab's pipeline, please let me know if you have a better way to do it.

Why the app cannot access the mssql service?
This is the error I get:

```
[...]
Status: Downloaded newer image for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.100-alpine3.14-amd64
=Building...
=info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 6.0.0 initialized 'CatalogDb' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer:6.0.0' with options: None
Unhandled exception. Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)
[...]
```

And this is the connection string that I'm using in the `appsettings.json` file:

```json
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "CatalogDb": "Password=****;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=SA;Database=CatalogDb;Server=mcr.microsoft.com__mssql__server"
},
```

If I run the following pipeline with the .net sdk image then the app starts and can connect to the db.
But in this way I cannot use newman to test it. Or can I?

```yaml
build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - docker
  image: 
    name: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - dotnet build ./CatalogService.csproj --configuration Release --no-self-contained
    - dotnet run --project ./CatalogService.csproj
  variables: 
    ErrorActionPreference: stop
```

## Update

I added an alias and updated the connection string to the service but it still not connecting.

```yaml
services:
  - name: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU14-ubuntu-20.04
    alias: mssql
  - docker:19.03.12-dind
```

`Password=*****;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=SA;Database=CatalogDb;Server=mssql`

I also added the variable `FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD` as specified [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/14.5/ee/ci/services/index.html#using-services-with-docker-run-docker-in-docker-side-by-side) but the app is still not connecting to the DB

```yaml
postman_tests:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - docker
  variables:
    FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD: "true"
  script:
    - docker run -p 5555:80 -v $(pwd)/CatalogService/:/app/ -w /app -e ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80 -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development -t mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.100-alpine3.14-amd64 dotnet run --project ./CatalogService.csproj
    - sleep 120s
    - docker run -v $(pwd)/test:/etc/newman -t postman/newman:alpine run "CatalogService.postman_collection.json" --reporters="cli"
```

## Update With Complete .yml file

This pipeline has 3 stages:

1. build/publish the source
2. build the docker image to test the application
3. test the application with a db and postman

```yaml
variables:
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
  REGISTRY_TENANT: TTT
  REGISTRY_URL: UUU
  REGISTRY_NAME: NNN
  IMAGE_NAME: image

stages:
  - build
  - docker
  - test

buld_source:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - docker
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
  script:
    - dotnet clean
    - dotnet build /builds/xxx.sln --configuration Release
    - dotnet publish /builds/xxx1.csproj --output ./publish/xxx1
    - dotnet publish /builds/xxx2.csproj --output ./publish/xxx2
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./publish/*
    expire_in: 1 hour
  variables: 
    ErrorActionPreference: stop
     
docker_test_image:
  stage: docker
  needs: ["buld_source"]
  tags:
    - docker
  variables:
    RUNTIME_IMAGE: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  services:
    - docker:20.10.12-dind
  script:
    # Prepare Dockerfile
    - sed -i "s~\$DOCKERIMAGE~$RUNTIME_IMAGE~g" Dockerfile
    - sed -i 's/\$ENVIRONMENT/Testing/g' Dockerfile
    - sed -i "s/\$ENTRYPOINT/xxx1.dll/g" Dockerfile
    - cat Dockerfile

    # Process Dockerfile
    - docker login $REGISTRY_URL -u $REGISTRY_NAME -p $REGISTRY_PASS
    - docker build --tag "$REGISTRY_URL/$IMAGE_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA" .
    - docker push "$REGISTRY_URL/$IMAGE_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA"

postman_tests:
  stage: test
  needs: ["docker_test_image"]
  tags:
    - docker
  services:
    - docker:20.10.12-dind
  dependencies: []
  variables:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  before_script:
    - docker login $REGISTRY_URL -u $REGISTRY_NAME -p $REGISTRY_PASS
  script:
    - docker network create -d bridge network
    - docker run --name mcr.microsoft.com__mssql__server --network network -p 1433:1433 -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=ppp" -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    - sleep 30s
    - docker logs mcr.microsoft.com__mssql__server
    - docker run --network network --name xxx1 -p 5535:5535 -d $REGISTRY_URL/$IMAGE_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
    - sleep 30s
    - docker logs xxx1
    - docker run --network network -v $(pwd)/test:/etc/newman -t postman/newman:alpine run "xxx1.postman_collection.json" --reporters="cli"
    - sleep 5s
    - docker rmi -f $REGISTRY_URL/$IMAGE_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
```

Comment: You would normally give the services in your docker-compose.yml file names. You can then use those as hostnames, resolvable within the composition's bridge (or other) network, in your connection strings, etc..

Comment: Once you get connectivity sorted out, you're likely going to have login issues. You don't seem to have any configuration/scripts to create the CatalogDb, so your connection from the CatalogService won't be able to complete its login.

Comment: Hi, the app uses entity framework and it creates everything on its own. I tried also to use the service name but it is still not working (about to update the question with this)

Comment: See how I setup SQL from a Docker Container here, sorry don't have time to help: https://github.com/MeaningOfLights/containers_artifacts/blob/main/dockerfiles/Dockerfile_3

Comment: Hi I see that you're setting some variables but where do you launch the mssql container?

Comment: Sure, EF creates tables on its own. The database itself has to already exist for the login against it to succeed, though.

Comment: If you look at Jeremy Thompson's git repo you can see him creating the database in the [day1-commands](https://github.com/MeaningOfLights/containers_artifacts/blob/main/commands/day1-commands) file.

Comment: EF creates the database as well, thanks for the hint on the file though. I'm trying to see if there is something on it that I'm missing on my pipeline

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the `--network=host` parameter on the `docker run commands`.
Now the app connects successfully with the db.

Comment: hi, I'm having a similar problem with your situation. could you post the complete `gitlab-ci.yml` that you execute? I couldn't quite get what you changed since your original post.

Comment: Hi, I added the parts of my pipeline file that should help you. The 30s sleep times are because sometimes the apps are slow to come alive and ready